# While & For-Loops

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, while-loop

I don't understand why this function works as a While-Loop, but not as a For-Loop. I am trying to count to 10 and print to console on each iteration.

While-Loop:

```
function oneToTenW() {
  var x = 0;
  while(x < 10) {
    x++;
    console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
  }
}
```

For-Loop:

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++);
  console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
```

When I call the While-Loop, I get this:

```
oneToTen();
x is equal to 1
x is equal to 2
x is equal to 3
x is equal to 4
x is equal to 5
x is equal to 6
x is equal to 7
x is equal to 8
x is equal to 9
x is equal to 10
```

Whereas when I call the For-Loop, I get this:

```
oneToTenf();
x is equal to 10
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the semicolon behind the for?

Comment: as @Trudbert says, just use the brackets for yield the iterations

Comment: I don't think it's a typo, I think it's a misundestanding of where `;` goes on `for` loops. There's a difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You're correct! Thanks. I deliberately put it there, but will go back and review my notes. Thanks.

Comment: @Padawan: If you're ever unsure about the proper syntax of a basic language construct, then it's a good idea to review documentation to make sure your syntax is correct. MDN is a decent resource for this. [MDN `for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I tend to include "cognitive typos" as a valid reason to close. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This line right here:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++);
```

Because you have a semicolon at the end, the statement effectively terminates there, and the loop executes without doing anything. To have the loop execute the statement below it, you need to include that statement in the loop body, by removing the semicolon:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
  console.log ("x is equal to " + x); // <- the line immediately after the for statement will be executed on every iteration
```

Or by enclosing the statement or statements to be executed in a block (braces):

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
```

Now the statement will be executed every time that the loop iterates.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a semicolon after the for loop, so it's looping over nothing. Try deleting that semicolon, and perhaps adding some brackets like you did with the while loop.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have an extra semicolon

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++);
  // Here -------------------^
  console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
```

So the loop body consists entirely of the empty statement (`;`). When it completes, then the `console.log` line runs to show the current value of `x`, which is now `10`.

To put the `console.log` line in the loop body, technically all you have to do is remove the `;`:

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
```

...although I always use the block (`{}`) on control structures:

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
  }
}
```

Either of those would show you the values `0` through `9`, because a `for` loop works like this:

1. Do the initialization (`x = 0`)
2. Do the loop body
3. Do the increment (`x++`)
4. Do the test (`x < 10`)
5. If the test is true, return to step 2

Comment: Excellent explanation. A good walk-through of the For-Loop. Thanks T.J.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you put `;` at the end of the `for` line:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++);
```

That's putting an empty statement as the body of the `for` loop, and the `console.log()` statement is run *after* the loop finishes.

It should be:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an extra semicolon. Try the below one

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
  console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, but I will say anyway,

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++); < Issue is right there. 
     console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
}
```

If you do this

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
     console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
  }
}
```

then it will give you the result you wanted. Braces and semicolons man.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the body of the for loop

```
function oneToTenF() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    console.log ("x is equal to " + x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically the body of the loop isn't missing. It just happens to be a statement that doesn't do what the OP wants. But your solution is of course correct. :-)